# What is the best way to upgrade existing large cordova android project?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-android

I have project in cordova 6.5 (android 5.0.0) and want update it to newest cordova and android with all attached existing packages - what way can be least painful?

Comment: The best way to upgrade to latest version is to simply remove the Android platform from your project and re-add it with the new version. For example,

cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@7.X.X [read more...](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/upgrade.html)

Comment: @JunJieWang my biggest problem is that I have a lot of additional packages installed and all of them got outdated, when I updated them I got an infinite number of errors and crashes - that's why I'm looking for better way to do this, if any exists.